# How to force a background image to have a fixed width in pixels

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a website and I have a background-image attribute on the body. I want the background image to have a specified width in pixels, but I can't find anything that works.

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Birds/H-P/mallard-male-standing.jpg.adapt.945.1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCType html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that image your trying to use in your code.... As that didn't work for me, if i change that to a local image it works fine.

Comment: Someone just posted the answer and it got downvoted for some reason, now its gone, but the `background-size` property is what you need.

Comment: I love that you put an emoticon in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477915737647-b5246ee6de6f?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=");
  background-size: 500px auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center; 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCType html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.your-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```